# ¿Como contar las letras totales?

Tags: java

El programa tiene que ser que lo que escriba por teclado, cuente cada letra y por ultimo diga el total de letras que hay, mi código hasta el momento es este:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    public class c {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println ("Por favor introduzca una cadena por teclado:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            String palabra="";
            palabra=sc.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Letra (i+1)+":"+palabra.substring(i,i+1));

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(palabra);

                System.out.println (st.countTokens());      
          }     
    }

}
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta? QUé problema tienes con el código que compartes?

Answer (score 4):

En este caso si solo deseas contar las letras totales, simplemente considera eliminar los espacios mediante:

```
  palabra=palabra.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

ejemplo:

```
  System.out.println ("Por favor introduzca una cadena por teclado:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        String palabra="";
        palabra=sc.nextLine();
        palabra=palabra.replaceAll("\\s","");
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Letra "+(i+1)+": "+palabra.substring(i, i+1));
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(palabra);
            System.out.println (st.countTokens());
      }
```

---

Incluso su únicamente deseas que "cuente cada letra y por ultimo diga el total de letras que hay", se puede realizar de esta forma mas simplificada, convirtiendo la cadena a un arreglo de caracteres:

```
char[] charArray = palabra.toCharArray();
```

Ejemplo:

```
String palabra="";
palabra=sc.nextLine();
palabra=palabra.replaceAll("\\s","");

char[] charArray = palabra.toCharArray(); 

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Letra " + (i+1) + ": " + charArray[i]);
}

System.out.println ("total letras : " + palabra.length());
```

Ejemplo Entrada y Salida:

```
Por favor introduzca una cadena por teclado:
Hola Jose
Letra 1: H
Letra 2: o
Letra 3: l
Letra 4: a
Letra 5: J
Letra 6: o
Letra 7: s
Letra 8: e
total letras : 8
```

Comment: Si justo asi gracias

Comment: @Jose marca la respuesta valida, si te solucionó el problema

Answer (score 1):

Si por letras te refieres a caracteres A-Z y a-z, si tener en cuenta ningún valor númerico:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String palabra = "Palabra 329023";
    int contadorLetras  = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= palabra.length() -1 ;i++) {
        if(esLetra(palabra.charAt(i))) {
            contadorLetras++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total letras="+contadorLetras);


}

private static boolean esLetra(char letra) {
    if ((letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z') || (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Java tiene funciones como `Character.isLetter(char letra)` para validar si un carácter es una letra, pero este método aceptar valores UNICODE, por lo que el contador de letras aumentara si envías valores UNICODE valido en tu String como por ejemplo `\\U2219`.

Answer (score 0):

sencillo, simplemente usa el método length que devuelve la longitud de una cadena de caracteres

```
String palabra = "palabra"
System.out.println(palabra.length);
```

el metodo length devuelve la cantidad de caracteres que hay en una cadena, entonces si tu palabra es por ejemplo "casa" almacenado en la variable palabra, debes imprimir palabra.length y este método va a retornar 4, porque casa tiene 4 letras

Comment: Eso esta bien pero para hacerlo poniéndola por teclado, igual tenia que a ver especificado en la pregunta pero el programa tiene que ser que lo que escriba por teclado cuente cada letra y por ultimo diga el total de letras que hay(tenia que haberlo puesto así en la descripción de la pregunta lo siento).

Comment: @Jose si crees que puedes editar la pregunta y dar más aclaraciones, vas a tener más probabilidades de que te ayude alguien. Estaría bien que indicases un caso de ejemplo, e indicases que salida por pantalla se espera para dicho ejemplo.